# What is the best wifi adapter to replace/upgrade the ASUS ROG G750JM's internal wifi adapter?

Tags: laptop, gaming, wireless

My research so far has shown me it's [possible to replace or upgrade](https://youtu.be/qsv8Vtml-E0) the ASUS ROG G750JM's wifi adapter.

What is the best wifi adapter to replace the ASUS ROG G750JM's internal wifi adapter? As I'm currently considering upgrading mine.

Adapter which comes with the laptop is: Broadcom 802.11ac

Although I acknowledge this thread topic has been discussed [(in 2014)](https://rog.asus.com/forum/showthread.php?54171-ASUS-ROG-G750JM-wireless-adapter) and the user *Dinooz* suggested: AzureWave (Broadcom) AWCE123H BCM94352HMB.

As the above thread is reasonably old, I wanted to confirm whether the AzureWave (Broadcom) AWCE123H BCM94352HMB is still the best wifi adapter to replace the ASUS ROG G750JM's internal wifi adapter, or whether a superior recommended replacement adapter now exists?

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with your current wifi card? I doubt you're able to hit the 1.3 gigabits per second (Gbps) standard max unless you have some seriously decked out personal file servers in your house on your router.

Comment: It can't detect or connect to the 5G band.